# How to install javafx in IntelliJ on Mac?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, installation

I am trying to start a javafx project on my intellij software but I am having a lot of problems. I read the guide and was told to download the javafx-dsk which I did, but when I created a new project and clicked "add jdk" and selected the javafx file it told me "The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK". Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? I am a Mac user by the way.

Comment: Have you also installed pure Java development kit?

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction

Comment: JavaFX is not a JDK, as JavaFX has been separated since JDK 11.  You point IntelliJ to your Java JDK location, usually `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/whateverJDKversionYouAreUsing/Contents/Home` and set an environment variable for `PATH_TO_FX` pointing to where you downloaded your version of JavaFX.  You never said if you were using Maven, Gradle, or what.. if modular or non-modular....

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use Apache Maven to drive your project in IntelliJ, as explained [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven).

Use one of these Maven archetypes

https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-archetypes

In your Maven POM file, add an entry for a plugin.

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>HelloFX</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And add an entry for a dependency of the OpenFX libraries.

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>14</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

## Install JDK

First, you must install a JDK on your machine. Your app under development will run using that JDK as its JVM.

By the way, know that IntelliJ itself is a Java app. IntelliJ comes bundled with its own JVM nested inside itself. So IntelliJ does not use your JDK to run itself, but does use your JDK to run your app under development. Java provides a mechanism by which a debugger in one JVM (running IntelliJ) can can connect to another JVM (your app running in your downloaded JDK’s JVM).

Here is a flowchart I made to help guide you in selecting a vendor for a Java implementation.

[image]

## Install JavaFX libraries

Next, you need to obtain an implementation of JavaFX.

Previously Oracle published an implementation. This implementation was bundled with some versions of Oracle’s JDK product, *Oracle JDK*. Neither of these are currently true.

In recent years, Oracle open-sourced the JavaFX project as *OpenJFX*. This source code is housed as a sub-project on the *OpenJDK* project. Future development of JavaFX is being driven by the Gluon company.

You have 3 options for obtaining an implementation of JavaFX technology. All three derive from the *OpenJFX* source code.

- Manual download from [OpenJFX.io](https://openjfx.io/) site. Then manually configure your project in your IDE to point to those downloaded libraries.
- Use a dependency manager such as Maven or Gradle to automatically download a copy of the library and point your IDE to that copy. This approach is what I use personally.
- As your own JDK discussed at the top of this Answer, obtain a JDK that comes bundled with the OpenJFX libraries. I know of two: ZuluFX by Azul Systems, and LibericaFX from BellSoft.

I use Maven approach myself. So I start a new JavaFX project by using on the the JavaFX archetypes available on Maven. There is an archetype for projects using straight Java code. And there is another archetype for projects using [FXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FXML).

See [this page](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven) for instructions on using Maven with OpenJFX.

In your Maven POM file, add an entry for a plugin.

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>HelloFX</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And add an entry for a dependency of the OpenFX libraries.

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>14</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

## Deployment

For deployment, your users will need a JVM as well as the JavaFX implementation in addition to your app classes. Likely you will want to include both within your final app bundle.

Alternatively, you could ship only your app classes alone, if you knew with certainty that your users had either:

- A JavaFX implementation on their own classpath.
- A JVM installed that bundled JavaFX implementation libraries. I listed
  two such products above.

## Resources

For more info, see:

- [Getting Started With OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)
- [OpenJFX project wiki page](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main)

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX is a **library**. You still need the regular JDK to use it. If you have already written Java programs in IntelliJ, use the same JDK that you usually do. You don't need to add a new one. Instead, you need to add JavaFX as a library dependency to your project.

Comment: Yes I installed the normal java jdk as intellij helped me with that, but how do you add javafx as a library dependency to the project.

Comment: @JacksonEtherchainStake See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/. Click on the IntelliJ link in the menu on the left.

Answer (score -2):

From the command line run this:

```
brew install openjfx
```

this worked in my case.